# Is there a particular name for when you pre-set a bunch of registers used for a specific task at hand?

Tags: vimscript, terminology

For example one could have many of these for different tasks (with different values for different registers based on the task):

```
function !RegisterTemplateTest() 

    # Set contents of said register
    let @p='andy'
    let @w='blah'
    let @b='someBunchahText'
    let @v='dfaskfasf'
endfunction
```

And have them setup with some sort of init function that calls them.

Comment: I have a side question: why do this, unless those registers are meant for interactive use? Jw, since I’ve not done it before, other than to create a macro and play it.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble define interactive use...

Comment: I'm aware of `c^n` and all of that...

Comment: I don't understand your question: Are you searching for a generic english term to talk about setting a bunch of data you'll need later like "setup" or "fixture" or something like this, for a term specific to vim about setting registers, for something else? Why do you need this term? I don't really see how it is related to vim or to a text editor at all.